# import esri Personal Geodatabase (.mdb) to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, esri-geodatabase, personal-geodatabase

I would like to import an esri Personal Geodatabase (.mdb) to PostGIS.
I have tried to follow the blog post:

[How to import esri Personal Geodatabase (.mdb) to PostGIS on Linux](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/how-to-import-esri-personal-geodatabase-mdb-to-postgis-on-linux)

I installed the GDAL tool suite (using gdal-110-1600-x64-core.msi), but whenever I try to run `ogr2ogr`, I get the following error:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=penusr dbname=my_pg_db password=my_pg_db_pass port=5432" C:\data\PROVINCES_2013.mdb -a_srs EPSG:26986
ERROR 1: Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=C:\data\PROVINCES_20
13.mdb,
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource C:\data\PROVINCES_2013.mdb' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> PostgreSQL
... list of many more.
```

Does this error typically indicate a problem with connecting to my Postgre DB, or something else? Am I missing some settings? I am fairly sure that the dbname and password are correct.

If I go to the ODBC Data Source Administrator window, I can see that under the Drivers tab PostgreSQL ANSI(x64) and PostgreSQL Unicode(x64) are listed.

Comment: What version of OGR are you running? Issue ogr2ogr --version, at the command line.

Comment: It looks like you are having an issue connecting to the MDB file (personal geodatabase), not connecting to the PostGIS database.  What do you get if you type `ogrinfo C:\data\PROVINCES_2013.mdb` ?

Comment: ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26

Comment: ogrinfo C:\data\PROVINCES_2013.mdb
ERROR 1: Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=C:\data\PROVINCES_20
13.mdb,
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
ERROR 1: Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=C:\data\PROVINCES_20
13.mdb,
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `C:\data\PROVINCES_2013.mdb' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  ...

Comment: Thanks @RyanDalton. I can view the data in PROVINCES_2013.mbd with MDBPlus, and it seems to be OK. I will try to read more about ogr2ogr to see if I am missing some settings, and also find some examples to run through the conversion.

Comment: I noticed in your error that there appears to be a space in your path where I put a question mark.  Check your code, or try putting the path in quotes.  _DBQ=C:\data\PROVINCES_20?13.mdb_

Comment: Thanks @RyanDalton, I think I must have introduced that space into my comment, it's just where the line wrapped in the error message. I think I have a problem with my ODBC settings. I have never used MS Access nor the MS Access driver, and I think I need to set it up for this ogr2ogr to work.

Comment: I have been trying to follow http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet, but still cannot get around the ODBC connection to DSN error.

Comment: I downloaded and installed FWTools for windows, and when I ran the same ogr2ogr command in the FWTools shell, it WORKED!! I don't know why it did not work in the GDAL (MSVC 2010 Win64) shell window. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to solve the "data source name not found" issue. ODBC reads the data source name (DSN) from a plain-text file in your home directory called **~/.odbc.ini** . Each .mdb file needs a unique DSN written into this file. You may be able to auto-generate it using GUI apps, but the ODBC developer recommends just using your favorite text editor to edit the file.

I have seen and used typically five descriptors for each .mdb:

```
[nickname_for_odbc_connection]
Description = Whatever description you choose
Driver = {FULLPATH}/libmdbodbc.so
Database = {FULLPATH}/yourfile.mdb
Servername = localhost
```

Adapt the above five lines to your particular circumstances, and paste them into the ~/.obdc.ini file, and that constitutes a DSN for that file.
This seems to solve the "driver not specified" error.

You will need to locate the driver you will use, in order to fill out that {FULLPATH}. Mine was not installed where others show it on their web postings from a few years ago, so the install-pattern of mdbtools may have changed; thus, seek it anew on your own system.